# One Click Unsubscribe from All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, unsubscribe

I'm looking to set up a one click unsubscribe page. Currently I have one set up for publication lists (pasted below). I'm trying to make this work for unsubscribing from all but inputting the all subscribers listid doesn't seem to do the trick. Am I missing something?

```
%%[ VAR @sid, @jid, @reason, @lue, @lue_prop, @lue_statusCode, @overallStatus, @requestId, @Response, @Status, @Error

SET @sid = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @jid = AttributeValue("jobid")
SET @listid = AttributeValue("listid")
SET @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")
SET @reason = "One Click Unsubscribe"

IF NOT EMPTY(@sid) AND NOT EMPTY(@jid) AND NOT EMPTY(@listid) THEN

SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @sid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)


SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode") 

ENDIF

]%%
```

Note that I've tried this code, but it doesn't capture the unsubscribe metric in the tracking section after it's been clicked:

```
%%[

var @debug
var @jid
var @listid
var @batchid
var @email
var @skey
var @reason
var @unsubscribeAll

set @debug = 0
set @jid = AttributeValue("jobid")
set @listid = AttributeValue("listid")
set @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")
set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @skey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
set @reason = "One-Click Unsubscribe"
set @unsubscribeAll = RequestParameter("ua")

/* if we know the subscriber */
if not empty(@skey) then

   var @lue
   var @lue_prop
   var @lue_statusCode
   var @overallStatus
   var @requestId
   var @Response
   var @Status
   var @Error

   /* if unsubscribing from all, then set the job, batch and listids to blank, effectively doing a global unsub */
   if @unsubscribeAll == "1" then
     set @jid = ""
     set @listid = ""
     set @batchid = ""
   endif

   /* create a request to inject an unsub event into the LogUnsubEvent platform table */
   set @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

   /*
    In order to invoke the request, we need to associate the following information with it to define the subscriber context and the job context:

    1. Subscriber Key
    2. JobId associated with the email send
    3. ListID the email was sent to
    4. BatchID the email was sent to
    5. Reason for the unsub
   */

   /* 1. define and associate Subscriber Key to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* 2. define and associate JobID to the request */
   if not empty(@jid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 3. define and associate ListID to the request */
   if not empty(@listid) then
     set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
     AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 4. define and associate BatchID to the request */
   if not empty(@batchid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 5. define and associate unsub reason to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* finally, you invoke the request */
   set @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

   /* extract messages from the response */
   set @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
   set @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
   set @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

endif

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("
jid: ", @jid))
  output(concat("
listid: ", @listid))
  output(concat("
batchid: ", @batchid))
  output(concat("
email: ", @email))
  output(concat("
skey: ", @skey))
  output(concat("
reason: ", @reason))
  output(concat("
unsubscribeAll: ", @unsubscribeAll))
  output(concat("
overallStatus: ", @overallStatus))
  output(concat("
requestId: ", @requestId))
  output(concat("
Response: ", @Response))
  output(concat("
Status: ", @Status))
  output(concat("
Error: ", @Error))
endif

]%%
```

Comment: Are you running this on parent or child BU? If child, what is the unsubscribe setup for that particular BU (unsub just from this BU or unsub from all)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is from the parent as we don't have any child BUs. When I say unsub from all I mean the All subscribers list which would include any future emails from any publication list

Answer (score 1):

If you want your subscribers to be unsubscribed at the All Subscribers level, remove the List ID from your script:

```
%%[ VAR @sid, @jid, @reason, @lue, @lue_prop, @lue_statusCode, @overallStatus, @requestId, @Response, @Status, @Error

SET @sid = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @jid = AttributeValue("jobid")
SET @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")
SET @reason = "One Click Unsubscribe"

IF NOT EMPTY(@sid) AND NOT EMPTY(@jid) THEN

SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @sid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)


SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode") 

ENDIF

]%%
```

That way you will prevent the subscriber from receiving any future communications, regardless of the publication lists they are added to.

For more details see here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/06/unsubscribe-and-log-an-unsubevent-with-a-logunsubevent-execute-call/

And the official documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.html